# Xamarin Forms - Access controls in Target application (iOS/Android)

Tags: xamarin

I am using Xamarin.Forms, shared project template.
Here, I add controls to the content page such as a Label through say framework provided StackLayout.

Now in target apps - say for iOS/Andriod, I just need to set some text for this label. I have some platform specific code where I want to change the text value for the Label created in Shared Project.

How to do that?

I understand, Custom Renderers could be used. Is there any straight forward way that I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You can, of course, use custom renderers... but imho it would be an overkill.
I'd use OnPlatform method - something like:

```
myLabel.Text = Device.OnPlatform<string>("text for iOS", "text for Android", "text for Windows Phone");
```

You can also do the same from XAML if you wish, like shown in this article (search "OnPlatform" there):
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/xaml-for-xamarin-forms/essential_xaml_syntax/

If the text you need is dynamic and you need to set it at run time from platform-specific project, than you need to assign your Label to some variable in the shared project and then reference this variable from platform projects.